# DebugView alternative for Linux (mono related)

Tags: .net, mono, log4net, trace, debugview

Under Windows we use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to monitor trace and debug outputs of our .NET application. Since we are currently porting the application to mono on Linux I wonder if there's a similar tool.

We're currently using log4net with the TraceAppender, but basically any solution that works with log4net would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [log2console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/) works for you. This software can listen to the output of a UDP Appender (with `XmlLayout` pattern). The application is written in .Net so maybe it is not too hard to port it to mono.

Alternatively you could use [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) (use the `XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j` format in that case).

Comment: There is an updated version of Chainsaw (soon-to-be-released version with lots of bug fixes, better support for search, filtering and tailing regular text log files) - developer snapshot available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: Somehow I couldn't get XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j to work but it still seems to be the best solution around.